# Setting figure size automatically when zero space between subplots (using subplots_adjust)

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'm looking for advice on how to write a subplot figure to file when there is no horizontal and vertical space between the subplots.  I want the size of the output figure to be chosen automatically so that the subplots are saved with no space between the figures, and I want to be able to adjust the overall relative size of the output figure keeping the aspect ratio the same.  At present I have to guess the output aspect ratio and set it with `fig.set_size_inches()` that will work.

The difficulty I have is that if I adjust the figure I have to 're-guess' what the the output size needs to be in order to output the figure with no space between subplots.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Change color of points on each subplot
cols = ['r', 'b', 'g', 'y']

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2)

for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):

        map = Basemap(projection='merc', lat_0 = 57, lon_0 = -135,
            resolution = 'i', area_thresh = 0.1,
            llcrnrlon=-136.25, llcrnrlat=56.0,
            urcrnrlon=-134.25, urcrnrlat=57.75, 
            ax = axes[i,j])

        map.drawcoastlines(zorder = 0)
        map.drawcountries(zorder = 0)
        map.fillcontinents(color = 'lightgray', zorder = 0)
        map.drawmapboundary(zorder = 0)

        lons = [-135.3918, -134.8331, -134.6572]
        lats = [57.0799, 57.0894, 56.2399]
        x,y = map(lons, lats)

        color = cols[2*i+j]

        pts = map.scatter(x, y, c = color, marker = 'o', s = 400, 
            alpha = 1.0, zorder = 1)

plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.01, bottom=0.01, right = 0.99, top = 0.99,\
    wspace=0.0, hspace=0.0)

outfile = "test_fig.png"
plt.savefig(outfile, dpi = 300)
plt.close()
```

This is what I get with the above code if I don't set the desired size of the output figure but ask for zero space between subplots using `subplots_adjust`.

[image: figure 1]

Now if I set the appropriate figure size (by guesswork), I can remove the space between subplots (adding the following before the `subplots_adjust` call):

```
fig.set_size_inches(5, 8)
```

[image]

The difficulty is that I have to find this ratio of width-to-height by guessing.  Is there a way to automate this process?